# Beamer: is it possible to mixed use different themes?

Tags: beamer, themes, headline

I usually use the `Warsaw` theme.
The head line will contain multiple lines if the document contains multiple sections.
Compared with this, I like the headline designed by the `infolines` outer theme.

Thus, I want to mixed use `Warsaw` and `infolines` themes.
More precisely, I need `Warsaw` with the headline from `infolines`.

I found the definition of headline in the theme file `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`.

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{infolines theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

I try to use `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[infolines theme]` after `\usetheme{Warsaw}`.
But it doesn't work.

But it works well to copy the definition body to set `headline` template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[infolines theme] % this doesn't work
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\begin{document}
\section{section~1}
\subsection{subsection~1.1}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
    page~1
  \end{example}
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection~1.2}
\frame{page~2}
\section{section~2}
\subsection{subsection~2.2}
\frame{page~3}
\subsection{subsection~2.2}
\frame{page~4}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like the picture.

[image]

I think it is not a good choice to copy codes to the preamble.
Is there some method like `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[infolines theme]` to let the headline look like `infolines`?

Comment: Just `\usetheme{Warsaw}` then `\useoutertheme{infolines}`? Beamer has five kinds of themes, and each of them can be loaded independently.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ `\useoutertheme{infolines}` is an acceptable choice. But this will change the `footline` (especially the colors) and blocks, and also including the margin of frames. It is better to only modify the `headline`, if possible.

Comment: Then I don't know better ways. Without loading `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`, option `infolines theme` for template `headline` is undefined. But when that `.sty` is loaded, side-effects other than setting `headline` template are introduced.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Oh, got it. It just likes the `\usepackage` command. It seems work to switch `\usetheme{Warsaw}` and `\useoutertheme{infolines}` in your first comment, and then `\setbeamertemplate{headline}[infolines theme]`. The margin is a little case. Could you change your comment into an answer? I think I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the workarounds from https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/388#issuecomment-296338235

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}[infolines theme] % this doesn't work

\makeatletter
\let\beamer@original@defbeamertemplate\beamer@defbeamertemplate
\def\beamer@defbeamertemplate{\beamer@sbtfalse\@ifstar{\beamer@sbtoo}{\beamer@sbtoo}}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[infolines theme] 
% This \set must be done manually, 
% since generally theme names have nothing to do with file names
\let\beamer@defbeamertemplate\beamer@original@defbeamertemplate
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{section~1}
\subsection{subsection~1.1}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{example}
    page~1
  \end{example}
\end{frame}
\subsection{subsection~1.2}
\frame{page~2}
\section{section~2}
\subsection{subsection~2.2}
\frame{page~3}
\subsection{subsection~2.2}
\frame{page~4}
\end{document}
```

[image]